# Using multiple arguments when defining a function without using if?

Tags: python, function, boolean, arguments

These are my instructions https://cs1110.cs.virginia.edu/pa05-maydate.html

```
 def creepy(x, y):
        x = (x // 2)+7
        y = (y*2-13)
        return x > y
```

I am supposed to be writing a file with one function: creepy. creepy should have two arguments, the ages of two people. It should return False if the two may date each other without being creepy, True.

X and Y represent the acceptable ages for two people to date each other. 
x = half your age plus seven years old 
y = twice your age minus thirteen

All code must be within the function. I know I am doing this wrong because I am used to using "Else/if" to get something like this done.

Any fixes to how I should define my function?

Comment: There is no need for the `if/else`. The function is supposed to return `True` when _both_ conditions are `True`: the first _and_ the second. Use logical operator(s) to translate this statement into python.

Comment: @DYZ i realize that if/else is not necessary for this. I am trying to return ''returns True if x is bigger than y, False if it is not'''.

Comment: You are doing exactly that. But this is a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have misinterpreted the question. The two conditions you mention from your source start with your age and provide an acceptable lower age limit and an acceptable upper age limit for a date. There are two conditions because for every input age there are two answers, a lower one and a higher one.

But your task is to take one pair of numbers, where the first is *always the smaller number,* and say whether the bigger number is higher than the acceptable upper age limit. So you only need one condition, not two.

```
def creepy(x, y):
    return x < (y // 2) + 7
```

Your source gives these as acceptable answers:

```
How old are you? 17
You can date people between 15 and 21 years old
How old are you? 70
You can date people between 42 and 127
```

We can test the function `creepy` by feeding it these numbers, like this:

```
>>> creepy(14,17)
True
>>> creepy(15,17)
False
>>> creepy(17,21)
False
>>> creepy(17,22)
True
```

These results match input 17; output 15-21.

```
>>> creepy(41,70)
True
>>> creepy(42,70)
False
>>> creepy(70,127)
False
>>> creepy(70,128)
True
```

These results match input 70; output 42-127.

If you want the function to handle the age calculation in the older/younger direction there is still no need for two conditions.  You can do it like this:

```
def creepy(x, y):
    if x <= y:
        return x < (y // 2) + 7
    else:
        return creepy(y, x)
```